# Unable to pass custom header in swagger Oauth

Tags: oauth-2.0, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, openapi-generator

In case of Oauth2 security type in swagger, there is one custom generated value(CSRF Token) that needs to be passed in order to execute the service for our flow to execute.
But we are not able to pass the value if it is not present in header, cookie or query string. Isn't there any way to pass a String type of input in request header using swagger?